# How come I cannot find rear calipers for a 2013 Outlander Sport ES, manual transmission?

Tags: repair, mitsubishi, parts, brake-calipers

So the calipers for my car seemingly don't exist. I need to replace the **rear right caliper** because the parking brake armature that releases the parking brake is stuck. So if I engage the parking brake, it is always engaged on that tire even once I release the lever. My current solution is manually releasing it (with vice grips, it is quite stuck) and using first gear as my parking brake and staying away from hills.

Every rear caliper I find at autozone, autoparts, rock auto, etc has the rear caliper without the parking brake lever attachment. The following picture shows the caliper I need. The parking brake lever is absolutely part of the caliper frame, if you look just above and to the left of the socket head, that rusted ball is the parking-brake cable. That pivot arm it attaches to moves the cable back and forth with the parking brake lever. How do I find this caliper?! I don't want to pay dealer prices.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How many miles on the car? The 2013 Outlander had a 5year/60,000 mile warranty (10year/100,000 on the drivetrain). If it's still under warranty, I'd call a dealer. If it's just outside on mileage, I'd still call them.

Row52 doesn't show any 2013 Outlanders in any of their yards in the US. So you're not going to get the part out of a junkyard very easily - you'd have to track down a specialist. I think the dealer would be the cheapest/safest option.

Comment: I bought it used from the dealer so there is no warranty according to them. I also am beyond 60k miles unfortunately. Am I having this issue cause I bought a non-popular car? I am bewildered that I cannot find a part for a 4 year old car.

Comment: How far beyond 60K? Might be worth a phone call to Mitsubishi themselves to see if there is any goodwill to be had. The problem with 4 year old cars is that they're too new to (generally) break down and end up in junk yards. Price the part at the dealer - you may be surprised that the part itself is quite reasonable, and you don't have to pay the dealer to install it..

Comment: 7k over. But when I bought the car CPO they told me only the 10year/100k warranty transfers over. I'm not talking about why I can't find it in a junk yard, why can't I find it from an autoparts store or warehouse?

Comment: Talk to Mitsubishi themselves and see what they say. We don't know why you can't get that manufacturer-specific part in an autoparts store, but knowing why not won't make the part appear on the shelves anyway.